# Google Chart Trendline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I have this data which I am using for the google chart trend(type=exponential) where I have setup  first column to number with below data.

```
[[{"label":"SecuredYear","type":"number"},{"label":"ValueInDhs","type":"number"}],[2014,14715525.225000001],[2015,14445752.777]]
```

but when the chart gets drawn its making 4 vertical lines from 2014.0 2014.5 2015.0 and 2015.5 but I need only one line for each year and is it possible that we can get the lable on point also how to remove y and x displays when hover over.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple options to correct the x-axis labels / gridlines...

1) use the `hAxis.ticks` option to force only two labels
(use `hAxis.format` to remove any commas / decimals)

```
    hAxis: {
      format: '0',
      ticks: [2014, 2015]
    },
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [
          {"label":"SecuredYear","type":"number"},
          {"label":"ValueInDhs","type":"number"}
        ],
        [2014,14715525.225000001],[2015,14445752.777]
      ]),
      {
        hAxis: {
          format: '0',
          ticks: [2014, 2015]
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'none'
        }
      }
    );
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

2) use strings for the year, instead of numbers...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [
          {"label":"SecuredYear","type":"string"},
          {"label":"ValueInDhs","type":"number"}
        ],
        ['2014',14715525.225000001],['2015',14445752.777]
      ]),
      {}
    );
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

if i follow *remove y and x displays when hover over* correctly,
use `tooltip.trigger: 'none'` to remove the tooltip on hover

```
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'none'
    }
```

as seen in examples above...

Answer (score 0):

```
trendlines: { 0: {} }    // Draw a trendline for data series 0.
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines

complete answer:

```
 {
    hAxis: {
      format: '0',
      ticks: [2014, 2015]
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'none'
    },
    trendlines: { 0: {} }
  }
```